# How to git clone a project in a specified directory in TeamCity?

Tags: git, teamcity

I am trying find out how you can `git clone` a project into a specified directory in TeamCity (2017.1.3)? I seem to not be seeing the option in the configuration settings. Is this not possible, or am I just not looking at the right place?

Answer (score 0):

There's an advanced option in `Version Control Settings` page called `Checkout directory` (you have to click `Show advanced options` link to see it).

There are some restrictions on which directory to use; please refer to the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Checkout+Directory#BuildCheckoutDirectory-Customcheckoutdirectory) for the details (e.g., the directory is not shared between configurations with different VCS settings to avoid clean checkout)